# missing ringing call in cdr table for asterisk voip

Tags: php, asterisk, voip, cdr

I'm making a php program that need to connect to voip
but only thing i need from voip is call log and who is calling so i can search in my contact table and show to user who is calling right now
i don't know anything about voip but i dig its mysql database and i found cdr table that give me everything i want.
so for now with 1 php file in asterisk server i can do anything i want.
only problem is:
its only add record in cdr table after call been answered or rejected or Unanswered
so there is anyway i can get call that waiting for answer and ringing right now from database or file or somewhere without learning all about voip or API? i mean easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDR table is CALL DETAILS TABLE.

You will get all details only at the end of call. No way here.

If you want more events, check AMI or CEL.

Comment: thanks for answer. my question was there is any file creating during ringing call or save record happen during ringning in another table or something so i can check that for example like every 5 sec or i must use some event and learn them for sure

Comment: or some premade php  files for call notification perhaps

Comment: YES. Check CEL. No, definitly no php files in asterisk.